# Unable to find ZEROMQTARGETS.cmake

Tags: cmake, zeromq, gazebo-simu

I'm trying to cmake a c++ application and get the following error.

**CMake Error at /home/prabhat/miniconda3/share/cmake/ZeroMQ/ZeroMQConfig.cmake:44 (include):
include could not find load file:**

/home/prabhat/miniconda3/share/cmake/ZeroMQ/ZeroMQTargets.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/ignition-cmake0/cmake0/FindZeroMQ.cmake:62 (find_package)

/usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:65 (find_package)

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/ignition-transport4/ignition-transport4-config.cmake:107 (find_dependency)

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gazebo/gazebo-config.cmake:197 (find_package)
CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)

**and line 44 of cmake is**

'''if(NOT TARGET libzmq AND NOT TARGET libzmq-static)
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/ZeroMQTargets.cmake")'''

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue ?
Thank you

Comment: Which libzmq version do you have and how did you install it? Which Linux distribution and version do you use?

Comment: Hi Vasil,I am using libzmq 4.2.2. I installed from thsi link here https://gist.github.com/katopz/8b766a5cb0ca96c816658e9407e83d00 Im on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Could you provide the full list of files in `/home/prabhat/miniconda3/share/cmake/ZeroMQ/`? Do you need miniconda3 for your application? The instruction you've used would install libzmq in `/usr/local` and not in `/home/prabhat/miniconda3/`.  Did you install zeromq with `conda` command as well?

Comment: Here is the list of files in ../ZEROMQ/  **ZERMQConfig.cmake** and **ZEROMQVersionConfig.cmake** I did not install zeromq with conda command. Is tehre a way I can move the install files from **/usr/local** to **/minicona3/..**

Comment: There is no way to move from /usr/local to ~/miniconda3. Better remove all miniconda environment variables from your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc and logout/login or reboot.

Comment: this seemed to work. I removed all of miniconda3 but now the error points to a location that doesnt exist on my drive        **CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Imported target "ignition-transport4::ignition-transport4" includes
  non-existent path\n

    "/home/prabhat/miniconda3/include"

  in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.**

Comment: Delete the `build` directory in order to clear the cmake's cache and then create it again to start from scratch. Another approach would be to try building your application in a clean docker container or in a clean VM, where you can install only the needed dependencies.

Comment: Deleted the build and created again. The original issue of the post is resolved.  I still have make errors but that is to do with gazebo-9, seems like.